# Terraform is not finding my passed json variables

Tags: terraform

I am fairly new to terraform.

I have a tfvars.json file which i want to use to pass my server configuration.

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "machines": {
    "master01": {
      "node_type": "master",
      "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
      "server_type": "cx21",
      "location": "nbg1"
    },
    "master02": {
        "node_type": "master",
        "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
        "server_type": "cx21",
        "location": "nbg1"
      }
  }
}
```

Now in my main.tf i want to create Instances

```
############## Provider ################
terraform {
  required_providers {
    hcloud = {
      source = "hetznercloud/hcloud"
      version = "1.26.2"
    }
  }
}

############## Variables ###############

# Token variable
variable "hcloud_token" {
  default = "<Secret Key>"
}

# Define Hetzner provider
provider "hcloud" {
  token = "${var.hcloud_token}"
}

# Obtain ssh key data
data "hcloud_ssh_key" "ssh_key" {
  fingerprint = "<Secret Fingerprint>"
}

# Create Master Server
resource "hcloud_server" "master" {
  for_each = {
    for name, machine in var.machines :
    name => machine
    if machine.node_type == "master"
  }

  name = each.key
  image = each.image
  server_type = each.server_type
  location = each.location
  ssh_keys  = ["${data.hcloud_ssh_key.ssh_key.id}"]
}
```

When i run

```
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply -var-file tfvars.json -state terraform.tfstate -auto-approve
```

I get the following error

```
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│ 
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "machines" but a value was found in file "tfvars.json".
│ If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.
│ 
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide certain "global" settings to all
│ configurations in your organization. To reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the -compact-warnings
│ option.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "hcloud_server" "master":
│   31:     for name, machine in var.machines :
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "machines" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a
│ variable "machines" {} block.
```

The warning gives some hint, that i need to mention this variable in the root module, but i don't even know what my root modul is, why is it not enough to pass the variables the way i currently do it?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, i updated the main.tf file in the question

Comment: where is your variable `machines`? Your code does not show any.

Comment: In my tfvars.json file

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for asking, I have some more variables missing `Error: Invalid "each" attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 40, in resource "hcloud_server" "master":
│   40:   image = each.image`
The same applies for server_type and and location. 

Adding the variable machine solved the first issue, but I am unsure if I am passing the information of tfvars.json at all. Might be missing a concept.

Comment: Hi, I posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186694/terraform-invalid-each-attribute thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message:

> An input variable with the name "machines" **has not been declared**

So you need to add to your  `main.tf` file `machines` variable declaration:

```
# machines variable
variable "machines" {}
```