# Terraform Invalid "each" attribute

Tags: terraform

I have a tfvars.json file which i want to use to pass my server configuration.

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "machines": {
    "master01": {
      "node_type": "master",
      "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
      "server_type": "cx21",
      "location": "nbg1"
    },
    "master02": {
        "node_type": "master",
        "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
        "server_type": "cx21",
        "location": "nbg1"
      }
  }
}
```

Now in my main.tf i want to create Instances

```
############## Provider ################
terraform {
  required_providers {
    hcloud = {
      source = "hetznercloud/hcloud"
      version = "1.26.2"
    }
  }
}

############## Variables ###############

# machines variable
variable "machines" {}

# Token variable
variable "hcloud_token" {
  default = "<Secret Key>"
}

# Define Hetzner provider
provider "hcloud" {
  token = "${var.hcloud_token}"
}

# Obtain ssh key data
data "hcloud_ssh_key" "ssh_key" {
  fingerprint = "<Secret Fingerprint>"
}

# Create Master Server
resource "hcloud_server" "master" {
  for_each = {
    for name, machine in var.machines :
    name => machine
    if machine.node_type == "master"
  }

  name = each.key
  image = each.image
  server_type = each.server_type
  location = each.location
  ssh_keys  = ["${data.hcloud_ssh_key.ssh_key.id}"]
}
```

When i run

```
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply -var-file tfvars.json -state terraform.tfstate -auto-approve
```

I get the following error

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid "each" attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 40, in resource "hcloud_server" "master":
│   40:   image = each.image
│
│ The "each" object does not have an attribute named "image". The supported
│ attributes are each.key and each.value, the current key and value pair of the
│ "for_each" attribute set.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid "each" attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 41, in resource "hcloud_server" "master":
│   41:   server_type = each.server_type
│
│ The "each" object does not have an attribute named "server_type". The
│ supported attributes are each.key and each.value, the current key and value
│ pair of the "for_each" attribute set.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid "each" attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 42, in resource "hcloud_server" "master":
│   42:   location = each.location
│
│ The "each" object does not have an attribute named "location". The supported
│ attributes are each.key and each.value, the current key and value pair of the
│ "for_each" attribute set.
```

I want to pass the configuration of the my servers via the tfvars.json at the top, however this errors prevent me from execution. I might be missing concepts of how to pass json to a variable in terraform so any reference to documentation is also highly appreciated.

Comment: How did it go? The issue persists?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `value` in `each` from what I can see. So it should be:

```
resource "hcloud_server" "master" {
  for_each = {
    for name, machine in var.machines :
    name => machine
    if machine.node_type == "master"
  }

  name = each.key
  image = each.value.image
  server_type = each.value.server_type
  location = each.value.location
  ssh_keys  = ["${data.hcloud_ssh_key.ssh_key.id}"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for_each` statement takes as input either of these:

1. **List of strings:** in that case `each` will take the value of one the strings in the list.
2. **A Map:** as you might know this data type has a structure that corresponds to a `key`: `value` pair. Your case.

In the structure you have, the `value` part corresponds to the attributes of your `object` (machinex). Then, in order to use the values, like `image` and `server_type`, you should be doing:

```
  name = each.key
  image = each.value.image
  server_type = each.value.server_type
  location = each.value.location
```

Just that, you forgot to place the `value` after each.